# browser/ballot.sol:102:16: ParserError: Expected '{'

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I'm trying to create an ERC20 Token just testing how it works, but unfortunately, I get this Error:

> browser/ballot.sol:102:16: ParserError: Expected '{' but got identifier
>   contract TEST TOKEN is ERC20Interface, Owned, SafeMath {
>                  ^-----^

The Error it is appearing here:

```
contract TEST Token is ERC20Interface, Owned, SafeMath {
string public symbol;
string public  name;
uint8 public decimals;
uint public _totalSupply;

mapping(address => uint) balances;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
```

Comment: It's the exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918349/browser-ballot-sol10218-parsererror-expected-but-got-identifier-contract/51920125

Answer (score 0):

Ops i could found the answer here already before posting my question, well if anyone have the same issue here is the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918349/browser-ballot-sol10218-parsererror-expected-but-got-identifier-contract/51920125